# Что за дополнительную информацию выводит sublimeREPL node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublime-text

Что за дополнительную информацию выводит sublimeREPL node при запуске скрипта js  и как от нее избавится?
Возможно надо REPL запускать с параметрами или аргументами?

```
> console.log("hello");

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("world");
}, 5000);

console.log("Bye");
hello
undefined
> > ... ... { _called: false,
  _idleTimeout: 5000,
  _idlePrev: 
   Timer {
     '0': [Function: listOnTimeout],
     _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     msecs: 5000 },
  _idleNext: 
   Timer {
     '0': [Function: listOnTimeout],
     _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     msecs: 5000 },
  _idleStart: 63765,
  _onTimeout: [Function],
  _repeat: null,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
> > Bye
undefined
> world
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REPL выводит каждый возврат из каждой строчки, которая является законченной функцией.
К примеру `console.log()` не возвращает `undefined`. Сначала он выводит в консоль информацию, потом производит возврат, который REPL выводит тоже в консоль.
Объект - то, что возвращает функция `setTimeout()` (т.е. объект таймера), чтобы в этом убедиться, можно сделать, например так:

```js
var a = setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('time is out');
}, 1000);
console.log(a);
```

Все действия с таймерами в nodejs расписаны [тут](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/timers.html).
Из интересного - есть возможность объявить таймер или интервал "не важным" для программы. Т.е. если у nodejs в эвент лупе остались только эти таймеры, программа закроется.

Затем, соответственно еще один возврат из `console.log()`

Comment: Понятно, как сделать так что бы не выводился объект функции , а выводился результат её выполнения как это делается  в браузере в консоли?

Comment: так это и есть результат выполнения, который возвращается через `return`